# Adding ajax call in a module for Joomla 4

Tags: module, ajax, joomla-4.x, com-ajax

I'm trying to add an ajax call to Article Latest module.

I added the code below to /modules/mod_articles_latest/src/Helper/ArticlesLatestHelper.php

```
public static function getAjax()
    {
        $data = ['test'];
        return $data;
    }
```

Then manually added /modules/mod_articles_latest/helper.php and added these code :

```
defined('_JEXEC') or die;
require_once JPATH_SITE . '/modules/mod_articles_latest/src/Helper/ArticlesLatestHelper.php';
```

Then I test it by call :
http://localhost/index.php?option=com_ajax&module=articles_latest&method=get&format=json

Those steps above are working properly in Joomla 3.x but I got this unsuccessful message in Joomla 4 :

```
{"success":false,"message":"Method getAjax does not exist.","messages":null,"data":null}
```

Can anybody tell me what I'm missing here?

Comment: What is the name of your class in `helper.php`?

Comment: @Zollie It's ArticlesLatestHelper

Answer (score 4):

To use J4 style or custom naming conventions with AJAX you have to convert the module to new service-based format. At a minimum, service provider (`services/provider.php`) needs to provide a module extension, a dispatcher factory and a helper factory:

```
defined('_JEXEC') or exit;

use Joomla\CMS\Extension\Service\Provider\HelperFactory;
use Joomla\CMS\Extension\Service\Provider\Module;
use Joomla\CMS\Extension\Service\Provider\ModuleDispatcherFactory;
use Joomla\DI\Container;
use Joomla\DI\ServiceProviderInterface;

return new class implements ServiceProviderInterface
{
    public function register(Container $container)
    {
        $container->registerServiceProvider(new ModuleDispatcherFactory('\\Joomla\\Module\\ArticlesLatest'));
        $container->registerServiceProvider(new HelperFactory('\\Joomla\\Module\\ArticlesLatest\\Site\\Helper'));
        $container->registerServiceProvider(new Module);
    }
};
```

The `mod_articles_latest.php` entry file is replaced by a dispatcher class. Default dispatcher factory constructs the class this way:

```
[Base Namespace]\[Application Name]\Dispatcher\Dispatcher
```

So with the above example namespace the class would be this:

```
Joomla\Module\ArticlesLatest\Site\Dispatcher\Dispatcher
```

You can use custom naming conventions, as well as inject dependencies by creating your own implementation of `Joomla\CMS\Dispatcher\ModuleDispatcherFactoryInterface`.

For the dispatcher you can extend `Joomla\CMS\Dispatcher\AbstractModuleDispatcher` or create your own implementation of `Joomla\CMS\Dispatcher\DispatcherInterface`. The dispatcher should fetch the data and render the module layout. If extending the abstract dispatcher, override `getLayoutData()` method to add the data you need. Strangely, neither the module extension instance, nor the helper is available in the dispatcher. You have to boot the module through application:

```
namespace Joomla\Module\ArticlesLatest\Site\Dispatcher;

\defined('_JEXEC') or die;

use Joomla\CMS\Dispatcher\AbstractModuleDispatcher;

class Dispatcher extends AbstractModuleDispatcher
{
    protected function getLayoutData()
    {
        // Gets some common data like application instance, module instance, module params, etc.
        $data = parent::getLayoutData();

        // Gets the module helper.
        $helper = $this->app->bootModule('mod_articles_latest', 'Site')->getHelper('ArticlesLatestHelper');

        $model = $this->app->bootComponent('com_content')->getMVCFactory()->createModel('Articles', 'Site', ['ignore_request' => true]);

        // Data array will be extracted to variables, i.e. this will be accessible as $list in the layout.
        $data['list'] = $helper->getList($data['params'], $model);

        return $data;
    }
}
```

Helper's class name is built simply from the namespace defined in helper factory plus the class name passed its `getHelper()` method. In this example, the class would be `Joomla\Module\ArticlesLatest\Site\Helper\ArticlesLatestHelper`. For custom naming conventions you could create your own implementation of `Joomla\CMS\Helper\HelperFactoryInterface`. Except that not really because `com_ajax` expects helper to be named in certain way. For this module `com_ajax` would always pass `ArticlesLatestHelper` to `getHelper()` method. So your custom factory would still need to be aware of this format. This was a really bad decision by the developers which partly beats the purpose of having such factory in the first place... This would have been better off with AJAX-specific interface.

Finally, some changes might be needed for the helper. Helpers must be instantiable, meaning they must not be abstract and must have public constructors (not necessary if using custom factory, e.g. which could call a `getInstance()` method on the helper). This is in contrast to J3 helpers which were entirely static (at least in core modules).

Comment: Great, clean answer, Sharky, as always. It is about how to build a module correctly for J4, anybody can learn from this a lot. The `com_ajax` problem however is still there - as you also mentioned that - it is looking for a helper class name like `$class = 'Mod' . ucfirst($module) . 'Helper';`. I think this must be corrected in the component too, at least with an added definition, to keep it backward compatible of course.

Answer (score 2):

I had two extra minutes to test this according to my previous comments under your question.

I created a `helper.php` inside the ArticlesLatest Module (root of that module) and created a class: `class ModArticlesLatestHelper`

This looks simply:

```
<?php
/**
 * @package     Joomla.Site
 * @subpackage  mod_articles_latest
 *
 * @copyright   (C) 2006 Open Source Matters, Inc. <https://www.joomla.org>
 * @license     GNU General Public License version 2 or later; see LICENSE.txt
 */

\defined('_JEXEC') or die;

/**
 * added helper.php for mod_articles_latest
 *
 * @since  1.6
 */
class ModArticlesLatestHelper
{
    public static function getAjax()
    {
        $data = ['test'];
        return $data;
    }
}
```

And I just checked the response on the URL you provided:

```
http://localhost/index.php?option=com_ajax&module=articles_latest&method=get&format=json
```

And I just got a success response with the 'Test':

```
{"success":true,"message":null,"messages":null,"data":["test"]}
```

So, it looks like that the problem was your inadequate class name inside your added `helper.php` file.

Comment: Hmm so ajax still doesn't work with namespaced module in Joomla 4? Indeed if I comment out `namespace Joomla\Module\ArticlesLatest\Site\Helper;` in file _/modules/mod_articles_latest/src/Helper/ArticlesLatestHelper.php_ and change the class name to `ModArticlesLatestHelper` I will get a success message.

Comment: @webchun - It looks like `com_ajax` still looks for `Mod` class prefix in helper class name. I know, others are also embarrassed as I’ve seen it.

Comment: I think an additional `if` block at `$class` declaration inside `com_ajax` could solve this problem, but I did not think too much about this yet… or I also do not see something here… looks a bit buggy…

Comment: I used to post this issue on https://github.com/joomla/joomla-cms/issues/32136 and https://github.com/joomla/joomla-cms/issues/32455 . Both of those ticket's  statuses are closed but seems the issue still persist?

Comment: @webchun- I do not see that they solved this problem, unfortunately at the moment I do not have more time to look into this more deeply.